# How to sed path with wildcard

Tags: awk, sed, grep

My path contains

```
/home/user/data/foo/test_foo.gz
/home/user/data/bar/test_bar.gz
/home/user/data/fub/test_fub.gz
and so on...
```

I am trying to print the 3rd line of all the .gz files

```sh
zcat /home/user/data/*/test_*.gz | sed -n '3p' > results
```

But this only show the third line of `test_foo.gz`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as `sed` only sees the stream sent by `zcat` which is the con`cat`enation of the uncompressed contents of those `gz` files.

You'd need to run one `sed` per file here:

```bsh
for file in /home/user/data/*/test_*.gz; do
  { zcat | sed '3!d;q'; } < "$file"
done > result
```

Here using `sed '3!d;q'` for `sed` to exit after the 3rd line so `zcat` can be aborted before it finishes uncompressing the whole file for nothing.

The `{ a | b; } < file` ensures that neither `a` nor `b` is run if `file` can't be open. In `a < file | b`, running `a` would be skipped but not `b`. In `a file | b` (for those `a` commands that can open the files by themselves), both `a` and `b` are started regardless of whether the file can be opened or not.

With the `zgrep` found on Debian at least, you can also do:

```
GREP=sed zgrep '3!d;q' /home/user/data/*/test_*.gz
```

`zgrep` there is a shell script that actually runs `zcat -f | $GREP` on its arguments (and prepends the file names using `sed` unless you use the `-h` option, though using `-h` with `GREP=sed` here wouldn't work as the option is passed to `$GREP` and `sed` doesn't support that option).

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline,

```
zcat /home/user/data/*/test_*.gz | sed -n '3p' > results
```

extracts the contents of all files matching the pattern into one single stream, and then pulls out the third line from that.

To get the third line *of each file*, you will have to loop over them:

```
for pathname in /home/user/data/*/test_*.gz; do
    zcat "$pathname" | sed -n 3p
done >results
```

This calls `zcat` and `sed` once for each file (assuming that the pattern matches something).

Answer (score 0):

Done using the `find` command:

```
find path -type f -iname "*.gz" -exec bash -c "zcat {}|sed -n 'p'" \; >>results.txt
```